# Passar uma variável de uma função para outra PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Olá alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou com problemas de passar parâmetros de função para outra. Não sei se estou fazendo certo, sou nova com PHP.

```
public function verificarCondutor(Request $request)
{
    //dados do formulário
    $cartaoRFID = $request->cartaoRFID;
    $cancelaTipo = $request->cancela;

    $this->indexJson($cartaoRFID);

}


 public function indexJson($cartaoRFID)
{
    $cartaoRFID = $cartaoRFID;
    return $cartaoRFID;
}
```

Comment: O que você fez está certo (se ambas as funções pertencem à mesma classe), mas como `indexJson` não tem utilidade alguma no exemplo fica difícil entender o que está querendo fazer.

Comment: dê um `var_dump` em `$this->indexJson($cartaoRFID)` e olhe se obteve o resultado que queria

Comment: Está tudo certo, só que você não faz absolutamente nada com o valor, se der um dd() ou var_dump() no retorno ou dentro da função, vai conseguir testar os valores.

Comment: O seu código tem erros conceituais, o seu código tem um método sem retorno e no outro você faz a mesma variável receber ela mesmo que não é necessário e para utilizar um método no outro é com a palavra reservada `$this` e o **nome do método**. O que você deseja fazer? [pode melhorar a sua pergunta editando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375345/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que faltou foi um 'return' no primeiro método.

```
return $this->indexJson($cartaoRFID);
```

Só que a segunda função não faz nenhuma alteração na variável.

Se queres retornar um json existe uma response... Tente no primeiro método.

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

Vai retornar todo o request.

Se queres retornar somente a variável no formato json faça.

```
return response()->json(['cartao' => $cartaoRFID]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Beatriz! Você tem nesse código dois métodos, que devem estar em uma classe. Partindo desse pre-suposto você pode passar parâmetros para um outro método utilizando o `$this`, que faz referência ao objeto instanciado da classe, obtém o seu retorno e salva em uma variável para usá-la posteriormente.

Dessa forma, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php

//...
public function getIndexJson($cartaoRFID)
{
    // Faz toda a lógica que precisa dentro dessa função.
    $indexJson = [];

    // Então retorna o resultado
    return $indexJson;
}

public function verificarCondutor(Request $request)
{
    // Salva os dados enviados pelo formulário em variáveis
    $cartaoRFID = $request->cartaoRFID;
    $cancelaTipo = $request->cancela;

    // Passar o valor de $cartaoRFID para o método getIndexJson() e salva o seu retorno na variável $indexJson.
    $indexJson = $this->getIndexJson($cartaoRFID);

    //... continua com a lógica de verificar condutor
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado. :)

Answer (score 0):

o PHP suporta basicamente dois tipos de passagens de parâmetros para funções: passagem por valor e passagem por referência.
A passagem por valor não altera o valor da variável fora da função após sua utilização interna. Exemplo:

```
<?php
function add_some_extra($string)
{
    $string .= ' e alguma coisa mais.';
}
$str = 'Isto é uma string,';
add_some_extra($str);
echo $str;    // imprime 'Isto é uma string,'
?>
```

Entretanto, se o parâmetro da função for passado por referência através de caractere `&` colocado imediatamente antes do parâmetro, o valor da variável será alterado tanto dentro quanto fora da função. Exemplo:

```
<?php
function add_some_extra(&$string)
{
    $string .= ' e alguma coisa mais.';
}
$str = 'Isto é uma string,';
add_some_extra($str);
echo $str;    // imprime 'Isto é uma string, e alguma coisa mais.'
?>
```

Além disso, se for utilizar orientação a objetos, você poderia utilizar os atributos de uma classe para modificar o valor da variável desejada dentro de um método, e poder acessá-la em outro método. Com base no seu código ficaria assim:

```
...
class Condutor{
 public $cartaoRFID;
 public function verificarCondutor(Request $request)
 {
    //dados do formulário
    $this->cartaoRFID = $request->cartaoRFID;
    $cancelaTipo = $request->cancela;

    $this->indexJson();

 }

 public function indexJson()
 {
    return $this->cartaoRFID;
 }
}
```